# Оценка сложности фрагмента кода

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Долго ломал голову куда бросаться подобный вопрос задавать, раз уж тема связана с программированием решил задать его здесь.

Задание звучит следующим образом:
Оцените сложность (число операторов присваивания) следующего фрагмента кода.

```
for (int k=0; k<n; k++) 
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) }
       if (c[i][j] > c[i][k]+c[k][j]) }
                c[i][j] =c[i][k]+[k][j];
```

Пример привел в точности как он был дан. Как бы вы подобное решали, если у вас есть только листик и ручка? И посоветуйте, литературу по этой теме. Заранее большое спасибо.
P.s мог ошибиться с метками, заранее прошу простить.

Comment: Точное число - разве что запуском :), а алгоритмическую сложность - O(n^3)...

Comment: какие то неправильны фигурные скобки, а так каждый цикл даёт n, в вашем случае их 3, поэтому O(n^3)

Comment: https://habr.com/post/104219/ - тут доступно описано вычисление сложности

Comment: Komdosh, да я тоже заметил, что скобки неправильные, но переписывал так, как было дано.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна оценка сложности алгоритма, т.к. нет понятия "Оценка сложности кода (и/или фрагмента). На хабре есть целая [статья](https://habr.com/post/104219/) на эту тему

Просто сам код как бы вы не расчитывали его сложность не с чем будет сравнивать. Число 11 информации само по себе не несет (для наглядности), а понятие сложности алгоритма существует